# how to use regular expressions in swift?

Tags: regex, json, swift

I am trying to write a JSON parser in swift. I am writing functions for parsing different parts of JSON code. I wrote a string parser which detects a string from the JSON data, by checking the start with \" and if I meet with another \" it is separated and returned as a String but when I met with this JSON text:

```
{"gd$etag": "W\/\"D0QCQX4zfCp7I2A9XRZQFkw.\""}
```

the function I wrote failed in the above case since in the value part it has to recognise the whole as String while mine is working to collect only

```
W\/
```

Since I gave the condition as starting and ending with \"
when I searched online I understood it is something in relation to regular expressions. So help me out to solve this!

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Use NSJSONSerialization (or 3rd party libs like SwiftyJSON).

Comment: @MartinR I really like the [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) library. But I think he's just wondering how to detect `\"SAMPLE TEXT\"` in a string.

Comment: I am just a noob to programming so I started doing as a project and get strong with fundas! And my main aim is to make it pure swift!

Comment: I am pretty sure that the question  how to parse a string with nested escaped quotes with regular expressions has been answered before. – Apart from that, parsing JSON with regular expressions is probably a bad idea (think of strings in an array of dictionaries ...)

Comment: I just realised swift doesn't support regular expressions and I just found another way to sort this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if first(jsonString) == "\"" {
        jsonString.removeAtIndex(jsonString.startIndex)
        for elem in jsonString {
            if elem == "\\" {
                s = 1
                parsedString.append(elem)
                jsonString.removeAtIndex(jsonString.startIndex)
                continue
            }
            if s == 1 && elem == "\""{
                parsedString.append(elem)
                jsonString.removeAtIndex(jsonString.startIndex)
                s = 0
                continue
            }
            else if elem == "\""{
                jsonString.removeAtIndex(jsonString.startIndex)
                break
            }
            parsedString.append(elem)
            jsonString.removeAtIndex(jsonString.startIndex)
            s = 0
        }
```

This code lets me solve my issue to keep it pure swift.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
import Foundation

let str: NSString = "W\\/\\\"D0QCQX4zfCp7I2A9XRZQFkw.\\\""
let regex = "\\\\\".*\\\\\""

// Finds range that starts with \" and ends with \"
let range = str.rangeOfString(regex, options: .RegularExpressionSearch)
let match: NSString = str.substringWithRange(range)

//Removes the \" from the start and end.
let innerString = match.substringWithRange(NSMakeRange(2, match.length-4))
```

Comment: my agenda is to keep the code pure swift and I realised that swift doesn't support regex and I just worked with something else to solve this

Comment: Yeah. I need to test out using regex with Emoji.