# regular expression - find a letter in by a specific template

Tags: nsregularexpression

I need to write a code about DNA.

I need to find between a str of multipal letters a seqence of 6 letters that need to be a match to the template.

For example: in index 0 it can be the letter A or T, that it, only those letters. What do I use to do this? Which type of function in regular expression ?

```
the_str = "AAATAAAATAAATAATAAAGAGCCAGAGGCCCTTGAAGAATGGATGGAAT\
TTGGACTTTAGCGGGGCTGGGGGACCCCGGAAATGGACGAGAAGCAGAAC\
CGAGGCCCTTTAGGGCTCAGCGGAGGCCTGCCTGTCTCTCTAAGGTCCCT\
CTTGGAGCAACTGAAGAAACTCCAGGCCATTGTGGTGCAGTCCACCAGCA\
AGTCAGCCCAGACAGGCACCTGTGTCGCAGTGAGTCCTGGTGCCCCCAGG\
CAAGCCGGGGACCTAGGCTTCTGTAGAGGGGCCCATAGGGAGGTGACAAT\
GAGTCCAAGCTCTCCTTGTGCCCCAGCTCAAGTATGATCCAGTCTGGTCT\
TTGGGGCCTCAGTTTCCCTGCCTGTGGGATGGAGATGCTTGCAGGGGAGG\
GGAGGGAGGGGGTGACTCTGCCGCTGTCTCCACCAGGTCCTGTTGCTGTC"
```

Comment: Are you coding in Swift?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use regular expressions in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29866470/how-to-use-regular-expressions-in-swift)

Comment: Please add the relevant tag to the question, we cannot help you if we do not know what is relevant for you

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like maybe you need something like this?

(A|T)AGCGG

That would match either AAGCGG or TAGCGG.

If the fourth character could be any of C, A, G then it might look like this:

(A|T)AG(C|A|G)GG